# javascript | string text between single quotes problem

Tags: javascript

the 'bg' is recognised as a variable .. its supposed to be text .. i also tried the double quotes but the url() only accepts single quotes url

```js
            var ahref = '<a href="#" style="background-image: url('bg');"></a>';
            var newhref = ahref.replace('bg', newThumbnailUrl)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is `bg` supposed to be a variable that results in a String of text?

Comment: `'<a href="#" style="background-image: url(\''+bg+'\');"></a>'` is foolproof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript string interpolation works differently.

You can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), using the backtick `` ` ` ``.

```js
var bg = 'your-image.jpg';
var ahref = `<a href="#" style="background-image: url('${bg}');"></a>`;

console.log(ahref);
```

Or you can concatenate strings with the addition operator `+`.

```js
var bg = 'your-image.jpg';
var ahref = '<a href="#" style="background-image: url(\'' + bg + '\');"></a>';

console.log(ahref);
```

The `url()` property does not *require* quotes, only in certain conditions.

> A url, which is a relative or absolute address, or pointer, to the web resource to be included, or a data uri, optionally in single or double quotes. Quotes are required if the URL includes parentheses, whitespace, or quotes, unless these characters are escaped, or if the address includes control characters above 0x7e. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url())

Comment: You may want those extra quotes like in my comment, for complex urls... but your solution should work in most cases.

Comment: @StackSlave, added. Nice catch!

Comment: thank youu that sloved my problem .. i've been searching for a solution for hours until you saved me :'( <3 thank youuu